# Adding images to the gridview dynamically gives out of memory error

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to add images to a grid view. The grid view looks like:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Khan on 29/05/2016.
 */
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<String> imageTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Drawable> images = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Drawable> images, ArrayList<String> imageTitles,ArrayList<File> files) {
        this.images = images;
        this.context = context;
        this.imageTitles = imageTitles;
        this.files = files;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageTitles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;


        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.imageButton = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.deleteImageButton);


        holder.imageTitle.setText(imageTitles.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(images.get(position));


        holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               try
               {

                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                   builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete image " + imageTitles.get(position) + "?")
                           .setCancelable(false)
                           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   if (files.get(position).delete()) {
                                       Toast.makeText(context, "The image is deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                       images.remove(position);
                                       files.remove(position);
                                       imageTitles.remove(position);

                                       notifyDataSetChanged();
                                   }

                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   dialog.cancel();
                               }
                           });
                   AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                   alert.show();


               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();

//                   Log.d("DELETE","Something went wrong");

               }

            }
        });



//        what happens when user clicks  on one of the images

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new
            View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    try {

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" +files.get(position).toString()), "image/*");
                        context.startActivity(intent);

//                        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, )); /** replace with your own uri */

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
//                        Log.d("GridView Adpater","The file path is" + files.get(position).toString());

                    }
                }
            });


        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        ImageView image;
        ImageButton imageButton;
    }


}
```

Now, I am getting images from my device using this method:

```
public void getImages()
    {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AppsEye");
        if(mediaStorageDir.exists())
        {
            String[] strings = mediaStorageDir.list();
            imageTitles = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strings));
//            Log.d(TAG, "the files are: " + imageTitles);

        }
        try
        {
            for(File file : mediaStorageDir.listFiles())
            {
                files.add(file);
                images.add(BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
//            Log.d(TAG,"Got some exceptoin ");
        }
    }
```

And setting adapter using:

```
        gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
//        Log.d(TAG,"I am gallery");
        getImages();


        gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(),images,imageTitles,files);

        gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

        return view;
```

The issue with above code is that on runtime, adding a lot of images to the `images`gives run time out of memory error.

```
                images.add(BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

So, to avoid above issues, I need to add images to the gridview one by one. How can I achieve that? Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass your images as drawables to your adapter. Instead, you can use the passed files to load your images. You will need to use an image loader such as [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to avoid OutOfMemory exceptions or laggy scrolling.

**Example using Picasso:**

```
Picasso.with(context).load(files.get(position)).into(holder.image);
```

instead of:

```
holder.image.setImageDrawable(images.get(position));
```